# Word-Wrap in Rich Text Area

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, rich-text-editor, richtextarea

I m trying to design a text editor in my website for which i m using rich text editor/rich text area.
But while using rich text editor/rich text area i m unable to wrap the words.
if a user is trying to write a statement without any space then the statement do not wrap to next line in place of that an horizontal scroll bar is generated in the rich text editor/rich text area..

Can any help me to wrap the content of the rich text editor/rich text area.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the CSS approach? In the end the text area is a generated HTML and it should work. Use word-wrap to break it into lines.

```
.break-word {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Comment: this css work well with my code but only in the case if the user is writing a proper statement with all space in between the words.
if the user is writing a word whose width  is greater then the rich text area width then the css is unsuccessful.

Comment: The break-word is to cater for long words without space. If you could post the html code of the Rich text area, it would be good. This is because the standard textarea should wrap any words within it's size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.breakword
{
     white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
     white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
     white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
     white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
     word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Reference : http://www.2lessons.info/2012/09/how-to-use-prettify-with-bloggerblogspot.html